# PJSUA2 version 2.13 video call

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pjsua2

I currently use to make SIP-Voip audio calls.

```
# Callback per ricevere eventi dall'account
class MyAccount(pj.Account,QtCore.QObject):
    chiamata = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    regChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    stateChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(pj.CallInfo)
    def __init__(self,endpoint,videoWindow,account=None,parent= None):
        pj.Account.__init__(self)
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self,parent)
        self.cfgChanged = False
        self.buddyList = list()
        self.chatList = list()
        self.deleting = False
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        self.videoWindow = videoWindow

    def statusText(self):
        status = '?'
        if self.isValid():
            ai = self.getInfo()
            if ai.regLastErr:
                status = self.app.ep.utilStrError(ai.regLastErr)
            elif ai.regIsActive:
                if ai.onlineStatus:
                    if len(ai.onlineStatusText):
                        status = ai.onlineStatusText
                    else:
                        status = "Online"
                else:
                    status = "Registered"
            else:
                if ai.regIsConfigured:
                    if ai.regStatus/100 == 2:
                        status = "Unregistered"
                    else:
                        status = ai.regStatusText
                else:
                    status = "Doesn't register"
        else:
            status = '- not created -'
        return status

    def onRegState(self, prm):
        self.regChanged.emit(prm.reason)

    def onIncomingCall(self, prm):
        self.call = MyCall(self,self.endpoint,self.videoWindow,call_id=prm.callId)
        call_prm = pj.CallOpParam()
        call_prm.hasVideo = True
        call_prm.statusCode = 180
        self.call.answer(call_prm)
        ci = self.call.getInfo().remoteUri
        user = ci[ci.find(":")+1:ci.find("@")]
        self.chiamata.emit(user)
        self.call.stateChanged.connect(self.stateChanged.emit)
        
# Callback per ricevere eventi dalla Chiamata
class MyCall(pj.Call,QtCore.QObject):
    stateChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(pj.CallInfo)
    def __init__(self, 
                 acc,
                 endpoint, 
                 videoWindow, 
                 peer_uri='',
                 media_cfg=None ,
                 chat=None, 
                 call_id = pj.PJSUA_INVALID_ID, 
                 parent= None):
        pj.Call.__init__(self, acc, call_id)
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self,parent)
        
        self.acc = acc
        self.peerUri = peer_uri
        self.chat = chat
        self.connected = False
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        self.media_cfg = media_cfg
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        self.videoWindow = videoWindow

        # Attiviamo la telecamera
        self.vid_win = None
        self.vid_dev_idx = pj.PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_DEV
        self.vid_preview_flag = False

    def onCallState(self, prm):
        ci = self.getInfo()
        print("onCallState",ci.lastReason,"<---------------------------")
        if ci.state == pj.PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED:
            self.del_call_scheduled = True

        self.stateChanged.emit(ci)


    def onDtmfDigit(self, prm):
        #msgbox.showinfo("pygui", 'Got DTMF:' + prm.digit)
        pass

    def onCallMediaTransportState(self, prm):
        #msgbox.showinfo("pygui", "Media transport state")
        pass

    def onCallMediaState(self, prm):
        pj.Call.onCallMediaState(self, prm)
        ci = self.getInfo()
        print("onCallMediaState",ci.lastReason,"<---------------------------")

        for i in range(ci.media.size()):
            print(ci.media[i].type)
            if ci.media[i].type == pj.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO and self.getAudioMedia(i):
                aud_med = self.getAudioMedia(i)
                self.cap_dev_med = self.endpoint.instance().audDevManager().getCaptureDevMedia()
                self.play_dev_med = self.endpoint.instance().audDevManager().getPlaybackDevMedia()
                self.cap_dev_med.startTransmit(aud_med)
                aud_med.startTransmit(self.play_dev_med)
                print("Audio onCallMediaState Ok")
                break

class MJSipRunnable(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.parameter_queue = Queue()
        self.chiudiEP = Queue()
        self.chiamataURI = Queue()
        self.setAutoDelete(True)
        class Signals(QtCore.QObject):
            codice = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
            currentCall = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
            statoChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(pj.CallInfo)
            regChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
            close = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)
            errore = QtCore.pyqtSignal(pj.Error)
            chiamata = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
            closeRunnable = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

        self.signals = Signals()
        self.signals.codice.connect(self.parameter_queue.put)
        self.signals.close.connect(self.chiudiEP.put)
        self.signals.chiamata.connect(self.chiamataURI.put)

        self.running = True

    def setUp(self,user,ipUser,server,portaServer,password,videoCitofono):
        self.user = user
        self.ipUser = ipUser
        self.server = server
        self.portaServer = portaServer
        self.password = password
        self.videoCitofono = videoCitofono

    
    def run(self):
        endpoint = None
        self.setAutoDelete(False)
        try:
            ep_cfg = pj.EpConfig()
            ep_cfg.logConfig.level = 0
            ep_cfg.logConfig.consoleLevel = 0
            ep_cfg.uaConfig.threadCnt = 0
            ep_cfg.uaConfig.mainThreadOnly = False
        
            endpoint = pj.Endpoint()
            endpoint.libCreate()
            endpoint.libInit(ep_cfg)

            # Aggiungi l'audio e il video all'endpoint
            endpoint.audDevManager().setCaptureDev(-1)
            endpoint.audDevManager().setPlaybackDev(-1)

            #Crea trasporto UDP che ascolta sulla porta prestabilita
            sipTpConfig = pj.TransportConfig()
            sipTpConfig.port = 5100
            sipTpConfig.portRange = 4
            endpoint.transportCreate(pj.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, sipTpConfig)

            endpoint.libStart()
            #Crea ACCOUNT
            acfg = pj.AccountConfig()
            acfg.idUri = f"sip:{self.user}@{self.ipUser}:5061"
            acfg.regConfig.registrarUri = f"sip:{self.server}:{self.portaServer}"
            acfg.regConfig.timeoutSec = 600
            acfg.natConfig.sdpNatRewriteUse = True

            cred = pj.AuthCredInfo("digest", "*",self.user, 0, self.password)
            acfg.sipConfig.authCreds.append(cred)
            
            
            myAcc = MyAccount(endpoint,self.videoCitofono)
            myAcc.create(acfg)
            
            myAcc.chiamata.connect(self.signals.currentCall.emit)
            myAcc.regChanged.connect(self.signals.regChanged.emit)
            myAcc.stateChanged.connect(self.signals.statoChanged.emit)

            
            exitCall = MyCall(myAcc,endpoint,self.videoCitofono)
            exitCall.stateChanged.connect(self.signals.statoChanged.emit)
            while self.running :   
                parametro = None 
                chiamataURI = None
                endpoint.libHandleEvents(10)
                try:
                    parametro = self.parameter_queue.get(timeout=1)
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    self.running = self.chiudiEP.get(timeout=1)
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    chiamataURI = self.chiamataURI.get(timeout=1)
                except:
                    pass

                if isinstance(parametro,int):
                    call_prm = pj.CallOpParam()
                    call_prm.statusCode = parametro
                    print(f"------------------> CODICE {parametro} {call_prm.reason}<--------------------")
                    if hasattr(myAcc,"call"):
                        if parametro == 0:
                            print("Chiude chiamata",myAcc.call,type(myAcc.call))
                            ci = myAcc.call.getInfo()
                            if ci.state == pj.PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                                myAcc.call.deleteLater()
                            else:    
                                myAcc.call.hangup(call_prm)
                        else:
                            myAcc.call.answer(call_prm)
                    
                    elif parametro == 0:
                        print("exit_call")
                        ci = exitCall.getInfo()
                        if ci.state == pj.PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                            exitCall.deleteLater()
                        else:    
                            exitCall.hangup(call_prm)
                    else:
                        print("exit_call_else")
                        exitCall.answer(call_prm)
            
                if isinstance(chiamataURI,str):
                    print("CHIAMATA IN USCITA ---------------->",chiamataURI)
                    exitCall.makeCall(chiamataURI,pj.CallOpParam(True))

            print("distrugge Account e Endpoint")
            try:
                myAcc.deleteLater()
            except:
                pass
            endpoint.libDestroy()
            self.signals.closeRunnable.emit()
            self.autoDelete()
            print("######################################## DESTROYED #########################################")
        except Exception as e:
            self.setAutoDelete(True)
            self.gestisciErrori(e)
            if myAcc != None and endpoint != None:
                myAcc.deleteLater()
                endpoint.libDestroy()
        
       

    def gestisciErrori(self,e):
        # global END_POINT
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        now = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        if isinstance(e,pj.Error):
            self.running = False
            txtMsg = e.reason
            obj = e.title
            err_code = e.status


            self.closeTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
            self.closeTimer.setSingleShot(True)
            testo = f"Attenzione!\nL'oggetto {obj} ha generato l'errore {err_code} dicendo:\n{txtMsg}"
            errore = f"{now},{obj} errore {err_code} -> {txtMsg}\n        -->{fname} {exc_tb.tb_lineno} {e}"
            msg = MJwarningBox(testo=testo,nomeButton=[QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Close],icon="Critical")
            self.closeTimer.start(10000)
            self.closeTimer.timeout.connect(msg.accept)
            msg.exec() 
            self.signals.errore.emit(e)
        else:
            errore = f"{now}: Errore nel modulo {fname} alla linea {exc_tb.tb_lineno} --> {e}\n"
        MJFunzioni.logError(errore)
```

I would like to be able to implement the video part as well, but I have not been able to figure out how to do it by following the official documentation of Pjsua2 version 2.13.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to be able to analyze an example of a video call made with pjsua2 version 2.13 using Python 3.10. I haven't found anything online, and following the instructions in the official documentation hasn't worked for me. Thank you.